# Is it possible to open a browser window in Ruby Shoes?

Tags: javascript, ruby, shoes

I'm wanting to build a GUI for a Ruby application I maintain using Shoes, but one of the things I'd like to do is be able to display network graphs using the D3 javascript library. After some Googling, I presume it's not possible to embed javascript in a Shoes app. Does anyone know if it's possible to open a browser window from a Shoes app, or better yet embed a browser window within a window in my Shoes app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you didn't mension the color of shoes so i'll use my favorite, green shoes

```
require 'green_shoes'

Shoes.app do
  gem 'watir'
  chrome_proc = Proc.new {
    require 'watir'
    browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
    browser.goto("http://www.google.com")
  }
  para link("Go to google", &chrome_proc)
end
```

Embedding a browser window.. I wish it could but i'd be suprised..
But you could use watir (html) as your gui all the way.

Here another way based on your comment, this is on windows but i'm sure you will know how to tranpose this to a Mac.

```
require 'green_shoes'

Shoes.app do
  proc = Proc.new {
    system('"C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" http://www.google.be')
  }
  para link("Go to google", &proc)
end
```

Comment: Sweet... I'll have to try this! I plan on using the original (C version?) Shoes. I assume this will still work?

Comment: As a side question... is it possible to make a system call in Shoes? I'll be running the Shoes app on Mac, and running `open <url>` from the command line does the trick. Any chance I can make this system call from Shoes and not have to depend on Watir?

Comment: sure, only with watir you have full controll over the started browser, see my updated answer, could you please accept my answer ?

Comment: about the flavour os shoes, i guess you mean red shoes, yes it should,  but i haven't installed it anymore so i can't test

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Mac and just wish to open safari

You can write the following:

```
require 'uri'

Shoes.app do

  background "#EFC"
  border("#BE8",
         strokewidth: 6)

  stack(margin: 12) do
    para "Enter your name"
    flow do
      @value = edit_box
      button "OK", width: 200, height: 200 do 
        system("open -a safari https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=" + URI::encode(@value.text))
      end 
    end
  end
end
```