# Launch a web url on link click - Ruby Shoes 3

Tags: ruby, shoes

How would I go about launching a web url e.g. https://google.com after clicking a link on Ruby shoes 3?

**I used the below code to no effect**

```
flow do
###
para link("some text", click: proc {
visit "https://google.com"
})
###
end
```

**And**

```
flow do
###
para link "some text" do visit "https://google.com" end
###
end
```

**Could someone show me how please?**

Comment: Anything that could be of help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the link using the method provided on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22431325/is-it-possible-to-open-a-browser-window-in-ruby-shoes)

```
flow do
proc = Proc.new {
system("cmd /c start https://google.com")
}
para link("some text", &proc)
end
```

Any further suggestions before I close this is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
flow do
  para(link("some text", :click => "https://google.com"))
end
```